# Numpy error when trying to process images with my code: "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'. Did you mean: 'ravel'?"

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

The code I'm working on to process images and make the bigger is giving a weird error:"AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'. Did you mean: 'ravel'?" It is doing this on the images that aren't already RGBA images and are instead color map photos.

```
# Import necessary libraries
import os
from PIL import Image
from random import choice
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy
#Define a function to process images
def process_image(file_path):
    try:
        # Open image
        image = Image.open(file_path)
        image = numpy.array(image)
        print(image)
        image = Image.fromarray(image, mode="RGBA").save(file_path)
        image.save(file_path)
        # Apply image processing
        for i in range(3):
            # Double the image size
            image = image.resize((image.size[0]*2, image.size[1]*2))
            # Blend pixel colors
            width, height = image.size
            list = [-1, 1]
            for y in range(height):
                for x in range(width):
                    # Get pixel color
                    pixel = image.getpixel((x,y))
                    try:
                        r, g, b, a = pixel
                    except:
                        r, g, b = pixel
                        a = 255
                    new_x = -1
                    new_y = -1
                    while new_x > -1 and new_x < width+1:
                        new_x = x+choice(list)
                    while new_y > -1 and new_x < height+1:
                        new_y = y+choice(list)
                    other_pixel = image.getpixel((new_x, new_y))
                    try:
                        r1, g1, b1, a1 = other_pixel
                    except:
                        r1, g1, b1 = other_pixel
                        a1 = 255
                        break
                    r_dif = r-r1
                    g_dif = g-g1
                    b_dif = b-b1
                    if r_dif<0:
                        r_dif = r_dif*-1
                    elif g_dif<0:
                        g_dif = g_dif*-1
                    elif b_dif<0:
                        b_dif = b_dif*-1
                    dif_sum = r_dif+ g_dif+b_dif
                    if dif_sum > 25 and dif_sum < 150 and a>20 and a1>20:
                        # Modify pixel color
                        def avg(num1, num2):
                            num3=num1+num2
                            average = num3/2
                            return average
                        r, g, b, a= (avg(r,r1), avg(g,g1), avg(b,b1), avg(a,a1))
                        r, g, b, a= (avg(r,r1), avg(g,g1), avg(b,b1), avg(a,a1))
                        def make_int(var):
                            try:
                                var = int(var)
                            except:
                                var = var + 0.5
                                var = int(var)
                            return var
                        # Set new pixel color
                        image.putpixel((x,y), (make_int(r), make_int(g), make_int(b), make_int(a)))
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error processing", file_path, ":", e)
    return image

#Define a function to process all files in a directory recursively
def process_directory(dir_path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
        with tqdm(total=len(files)) as pbar:
            for file in files:
                # Check if file is an image
                if file.endswith(".png"):
                    file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                    # Process the image
                    new_image = process_image(file_path)

                    new_image.save(file_path)
                pbar.update(1)

#Call the directory processing function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_directory(dir_path)
```

I have tried saving it before processing the image but it gives a buffer error but there is plenty of memory left. I don't really know why it is giving these errors. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Plase include the traceback of the error in your question.

Comment: Have a read through https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Comment: Don't catch all exceptions with `except Exception`. Don't catch any exception, specific or generic, if you're not handling it properly. If there is an error, and you don't (or can't) do anything properly in your program about it, the error should be shown and the program should exit; it should not heedlessly continue.

Comment: Since you catch all exception, that means that the line `new_image.save(file_path)` is causing the error. Which means `new_image` is a NumPy array. You return `new_image` from `process_image`, which returns `image`, *even if* there is an error. If the variable `image` is a NumPy array at the point the error occurs, an array is returned (since you don't really do anything about the error), and your actual error occurs.

Comment: Since the error has to occur in the line `image = Image.fromarray(image, mode="RGBA").save(file_path)` (since `image` is a NumPy array and not `None`, which it is if that line were executed properly, it seems likely that `fromarray` fails; possibly because the input `image` array doesn't not match the size excepted for the "RGBA" mode. You'll need to check the shape and dtype of the input array to verify that.

Comment: A PIL Image object has a `save` method.  A numpy array does not.  So you have to identify which line raises this error, and then determine why the variable (`image` or `new_image`) is an array instead of an `Image`.

Comment: i think you have broken a record for the world biggest `try`-`except` block. For this reason, i give the question an upvote.

Comment: Instead of `r_dif = r-r1; if r_dif<0 ....` try `r_dif = abs(r-r1)`